# DriveApp.getFolders() not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Apps Script for Sheets (running as a script under Sheets) that is supposed to return all the folders in my Google drive, however, the following code is stuck in an endless loop and only shows 1 of 3 folders in the drive - over and over again.

```
 //this doesn't work -only shows 1 folder and repeats indefinitely
function getMyFolders() {
  var f;
   while (DriveApp.getFolders().hasNext()) {
    f = DriveApp.getFolders().next();
    console.log("f: " +f.getName());
  }
}
```

The code returns the name of only one of my folders (hasNext() is clearly not working or there is a bug in Google Apps Scripts - since the while condition is never false (I ran it for several minutes and it never stopped!)

Could this be a security issue? This is just one of the problems I've run into.  The other is that the 3 folders are subfolders of the same parent folder. No sure why getFolders() is not returning just the parent (that would make more sense).

Comment: You should use recursion.

Comment: Ultimately, yes, but that doesn't solve this quirkiness of this issue. Just trying to get a list of all folders in one directory doesn't work like it should due to ".hasNext()" which is permanently stuck as "true".

Comment: You need to take the DriveApp.getFolders() out of the while statement like Ue.4 has shown you.

Comment: It is sometime possible to use Array.from() method to turn an iterator into an array.  But not always. For example it does not always work on html collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your function instead to return just the parent folders!

```
function getMyFolders() {
  let folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    console.log("f: " +folders.next().getName());
  }
}
```

If you want child folders as well, you would need to use recursion. Are you familiar with the concept? Happy to update my answer with that information if it's helpful.

#### Explanation:

You were calling `DriveApp.getFolders();` on every iteration, so `hasNext()` was always retrieving the same item (the first folder in the iterator). Hence, you had an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry Lle.4, your answer was correct!  There's a bug in Apps Script [editor] where it was trying to run the old function even after I commented it out.  I've learned to reload the Sheet page every 30 minutes or so.  By the way, that will show all folders - no recursion necessary. I'll mark your answer as the correct one when SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

#### Get All My Files

```
function getAllMyFiles(folder=DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next()
    sh.appendRow([file.getName(),file.getId()]);
  }
  let sfldrs = folder.getFolders();
  while(sfldrs.hasNext()) {
    let sfldr = sfldrs.next();
    getAllMyFiles(sfldr)
  }
}
```

Comment: OK - I see what you mean. I put in my answer to get all the folder names from a specific root. Strange way of doing things. I suppose the hasNext() doesn't update without recursion.  I get it. (coming from c#, this is counterintuitive to me)

Comment: getFiles or getFolders return interators not files

Comment: I never would have guessed that it's necessary to recursively call a function to get all the folders at the same level.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not necessary to get all of the folders but it is necessary to get the files in those folders and possibly the additional subfolders and subsubfolders.

Comment: Once you get the folders in a call to get folders they remain in that iterator until you flush them all out with next() calls.

Comment: true, I suppose I could write " while (sfldrs.hasNext()) ... " statements repeatedly, but that goes against reusability, so recursion is the only way for an undetermined number of folders. thanks again
Though, at that point, you could use an if statement instead of while loop (since you're not actually looping)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote Cooper's answer to get all folders underneath a given parent.
In my case the parent folder is called "Gill".

```
function getAllMyFolders(folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Gill").next()) {
      let sfldrs = folder.getFolders();
      while(sfldrs.hasNext()) {
        let sfldr = sfldrs.next();
        console.log("folder name: " +sfldr.getName());
        getAllMyFolders(sfldr)
      }
    }
```

Ok - I played around with this code and discovered recursion is completely unnecessary, so here's code that will return all folders at all levels, then you can test the level with getParents()

```
function getMyFolders() {
  let folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = folders.next();
    Logger.log(folder.getName() + ", Parent Folder: " + folder.getParents().next().getName());
  }
}
```

I had a hunch that using a recursive function was the wrong way to go (and it looks terrible plus adds unnecessary overhead) but was confused why, my first attempt in this question did not work. The answer was the way my code was written - apparently, you need to assign DriveApp.getFolders() to a variable only once. Simply putting it in more than once, seems to reset it.  That is, checking for DriveApp.getFolders().hasNext() and followed by DriveApp.getFolders().next() will cause the endless loop! Lesson here: assign it to a variable and then check for hasNext as calling it changes the state of the iterator which is reset again if getFolders is called again.
That was my actual bug here.

Comment: This `folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Gill").next()` works because it returns a folder not an interator

Comment: Good to know. (my first foray into Apps Scripts was 2 days ago, so these little gotchas have been driving me crazy). Funny, I tried ("Gill")[0] thinking it was an array. lol